# fscanf() how to go in the next line?

Tags: c, text, scanf, words

So I have a wall of text in a file and I need to recognize some words that are between the $ sign and call them as numbers then print the modified text in another file along with what the numbers correspond to.
Also lines are not defined and columns should be max 80 characters.

Ex:

```
I $like$ cats.  
I [1] cats.  
[1] --> like
```

That's what I did:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define N 80
    #define MAX 9999
    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        int i=0,count=0;
        char matr[MAX][N];

        if((fp = fopen("text.txt","r")) == NULL){
            printf("Error.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while((fscanf(fp,"%s",matr[i])) != EOF){
            printf("%s ",matr[i]);
            if(matr[i] == '\0')
                printf("\n");

            //I was thinking maybe to find two $ but Idk how to replace the entire word     
            /*                                 
            if(matr[i] == '$')
                count++;
            if(count == 2){
                ...code...
            }
            */
            i++;
        }



        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
   }
```

My problem is that fscanf doesn't recognize `'\0'` so it doesn't go in the next line when I print the array..also I don't know how to replace `$word$` with a number.

Comment: `fscanf("%s")` will just read one word. If you want to process lines, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only will `fscanf("%s")` read one whitespace-delimited string at a time, it will also eat all whitespace between those strings, including line terminators.  If you want to reproduce the input whitespace in the output, as your example suggests you do, then you need a different approach.

> Also lines are not defined and columns should be max 80 characters.

I take that to mean the *number* of lines is not known in advance, and that it is acceptable to assume that no line will contain more than 80 characters (not counting any line terminator).

When you say

> My problem is that fscanf doesn't recognize '\0' so it doesn't go in the next line when I print the array

I suppose you're talking about this code:

> ```
>         char matr[MAX][N];
>             /* ... */
>             if(matr[i] == '\0')
> ```

Given that declaration for `matr`, the given condition will *always* evaluate to `false`, regardless of any other consideration.  `fscanf()` does not factor in at all.  The type of `matr[i]` is `char[N]`, an array of `N` elements of type `char`.  That evaluates to a pointer to the first element of the array, which pointer will never be `NULL`.  It looks like you're trying to determine when to write a newline, but nothing remotely resembling this approach can do that.

I suggest you start by taking @Barmar's advice to read line-by-line via `fgets()`.  That might look like so:

```
char line[N+2]; /* N + 2 leaves space for both newline and string terminator */

if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    /* one line read; handle it ... */
} else {
    /* handle end-of-file or I/O error */
}
```

Then for each line you read, parse out the `"$word$"` tokens by whatever means you like, and output the needed results (everything but the `$`-delimited tokens verbatim; the bracket substitution number for each token).  Of course, you'll need to memorialize the substitution tokens for later output.  Remember to make *copies* of those, as the buffer will be overwritten on each read (if done as I suggest above).

Comment: I know that `fgets()` works the problem is that I avoided using it because It reads all the line so I don't know how can I only change the words between $ signs. I thought to read word for word and then if two $ sign were found I would switch the word with a number.

Comment: The fact remains that `scanf()` does not easily do what you want.  What everyone is suggesting to you is to use *string-manipulation* functions or even plain arithmetic operations to analyze each line after you read it, so as to pick out the `$`-delimited words.

Comment: Nevertheless, if you insist on using `fscanf()` to do your parsing, then you'll need to rely on the field descriptors that do not skip whitespace: `%[` and `%c`.  Such an approach would be tricky and a bit obscure, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf()` *does* recognize '\0', under select circumstances, but that is not the issue here.

Code needs to detect `'\n'`.  `fscanf(fp,"%s"...` will not do that.  The first thing `"%s"` directs is to consume (and not save) any leading white-space including `'\n'`. Read a line of text with `fgets()`.

Simple read 1 line at a time.  Then march down the buffer looking for words.
Following uses `"%n"` to track how far in the buffer scanning stopped.

```
// more room for \n \0
#define BUF_SIZE (N + 1 + 1) 
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
  char *p = buffer;
  char word[sizeof buffer];
  int n;
  while (sscanf(p, "%s%n", word, &n) == 1) {
    // do something with word
    if (strcmp(word, "$zero$") == 0) fputs("0", stdout);
    else if (strcmp(word, "$one$") == 0) fputs("1", stdout);
    else fputs(word, stdout);
    fputc(' ', stdout);
    p += n;
  }
  fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fread() to read the file contents to a char[] buffer. Then iterate through this buffer and whenever you find a $ you perform a strncmp to detect with which value to replace it (keep in mind, that there is a 2nd $ at the end of the word). To replace $word$ with a number you need to either shrink or extend the buffer at the position of the word - this depends on the string size of the number in ascii format (look solutions up on google, normally you should be able to use memmove). Then you can write the number to the cave, that arose from extending the buffer (just overwrite the $word$ aswell).
Then write the buffer to the file, overwriting all its previous contents.